# FirefoxDriver() methods are not displaying with cntrl+space

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am a beginner for selenium and I'm facing one problem that, I've created one project and in these I configure the build path of all libraries of selenium. But when I create a class and start code in main method that time when we click on cntrl+space to call methods its not displaying for `FirefoxDriver()`.

Please help me how to resolve this issue, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the Selenium Libraries, the `FirefoxDriver()` calls depend on selenium-server-standalone.jar.

- Download the latest JAR from [this link.](http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/2.41/selenium-server-standalone-2.41.0.jar)
- Assuming you have Eclipse, right-click your project, click Properties.
- Click Java Build Path > Libraries > Add External JAR and select the JAR you just downloaded.

Comment: I used this JAR file which you give and exactly follow the above steps which you told but not able to find this methods.

Comment: Hi Marck, Forget about Ctrl-Space for a moment, just try to use the FirefoxDriver() method. What error do you receive when you try to use the methods?

Comment: it gives error for import that method which we can do by this but all the time writing full text taking time, so it would be helpful for me if you give me the solution with ctrl+space.

Comment: Have you considered that your Eclipse may be corrupted somehow? Try all the solutions in [this link](http://www.mkyong.com/java/content-assist-ctrl-space-is-not-working-eclipse/) and let me know if that works.

Comment: May be eclipse was corrupted because I checked go through with these solution too, but its not helpful for me.. what you suggest for this issue?